# What is counted as a "low quality question"?

Tags: discussion

I flagged this question because of it's low quality:

[image: Low Quality Question]

- -2 Score
- No example code
- 25 Views in 14 days

I personally would call this question's quality "low" but when I came to check my flag it was "disputed".

What makes this question a good question?

Comment: VLQ is intended for things that absolutely need to be delete ASAP.  Just use other standard close flag reasons instead (like "too broad" or "off-topic > debugging")

Comment: [Question link](http://stackoverflow.com/q/31876421/4639281), for anyone too lazy to search for it.